# Why my thread doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I make an app that can count down. But it doesn't work and it just shows 100 in textview.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textView;
    private Button start;
    Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        start.setOnClickListener(onStart);
        thread = new Thread( //it's my thread
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--) {
                            Log.i("Where am I?", "I'm in for loop .");
                            try {
                                textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Exception.getCause", String.valueOf(e.getCause()), e.getCause());
                            }
                            Log.i("INDEX", String.valueOf(i));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onStart = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Where am I?", "I in View.OnClickListener .");
            thread.start();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));` should be on the ui thread

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead. Checkout: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Instread of Thread use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `TextView` using `runOnUiThread` as below...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override    
   public void run() {

       textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));

   }
});
```

**Update:**

For delay in count you can use `Handler` as below. Create an object of `Handler` and create a `Thread`.

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

         //add your code here which should execute after the specified delay

    }
};
```

Then pass that thread inside `postDelayed()` method `Handler` with the time which should be delayed to execute the thread as below...

```
mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 1000);
```

And if you want to cancel the thread to execute, use `removeCallbacks()` method as below...

```
mTimerHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerExecutor);
```

Comment: thanks for your ansewer.Could you tell me ,where do I put it in my cod?

Comment: how can I make delay in count?I mean ,I want it to count and after each counting , counter puas for a short time and show the number on text view,after that it continue it in same way...(100...99...98...97.....)

Answer (score 1):

Catching for `Exception` inside the Thread is kind of misleading. As matter of fact, `textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));`  executed in a `Thread` different from the `UI Thread` should make you app crashes for `CalledFromTheWrongThreadException`. You should use an `Handler` to execute that line in the UI Thread's context

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

has to be used in UI thread only.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

This is UI action, You can handle UI action only in a main thread.

You can send a message to the handle of activity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Thread class to interact with UI you should use AsyncTask or Handler classes.
Sample tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask instead.

Checkout:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html